# Geofire Not Updating my Location in the Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

The Firebase database is not getting updated with the location. Please help me! My Code is given below:

```
    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference DriverAvailabilityRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location");

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(DriverAvailabilityRef);
    geoFire.setLocation(userID, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), 
    location.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: you should update your location in addValueEvent listener method

Comment: Do you have an error? What is the value of `userID`? What does `location.getLatitude()` and `location.getLongitude()` return? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @WaleedAsim i am a newbie to this world. Can u please  give me an idea where and how i should do it!

Comment: @AlexMamo I am facing no error as such. The userID is the id of the logged in user which is diferrent for every user stored in the Firebase Authentication. The location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() returns the current location of the logged in user, i.e. the users lattitude and longitude.

Comment: All all of them correct? Are you sure, have you test it?

Comment: I could solve the problem!!! it was the firebase security thing where i kept it as uneditable.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yep. Its working fine now! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @RehaanMazid You're welcome!

Comment: @RehaanMazid have you solved your problem??

Comment: @WaleedAsim Yes i have solved the problem. Thank you for ur help!